# how to override ActiveJob to prevent serialization error?

Tags: mongoid, resque, ruby-on-rails-4.2, postmark

I'm using mongoid 5.1, devise, postmark for email sending, I overrided devise method as below:-

user.rb model file:-

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

Now, I'm getting "ActiveJob::SerializationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create" error, How to overrided ActiveJob to remove this error, Since I'm new to rails, i'm not getting any idea on overriding source code,I would be gratefull if proper technique on monkey patching or source code overriding is mentioned. Thanks, Happy Coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `include GlobalID::Identification` to any model send to mailer. `deliver_later` needs an id to retrieve again the model from the database.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid

Comment: thanks @TlmaK0, i will implement it as you said, if it works then will accept the answer if not then i will keep asking in comments : ) . Thanks again.

Comment: You save my day :)